# How to handle state, concurrency and JMS inside Spring controllers?

Tags: java, spring-boot, design-patterns, state

I'm building a Spring Boot 2.1.6 REST API in which one of the controllers receives frequent requests. Each request contains data pertaining to some client event. The client is a video player which sends events each time a user viewed a video, viewed 25%, 50% etc. of the video, clicked etc. There may around 20 events per each client cycle.

I need to save each event in the database. As far as I understand inserting an event into the database inside the controller is not the best solution because inserting in the db is expensive, especially if this will happen on each call to the controller.

Therefore I thought to accumulate the events inside the controller inside some data structure, perhaps a queue. Then when the queue reached certain size I'd send all the events via JMS service to a consumer which will update the db with all the events (in a separate thread).

Controllers in Spring are singletons by default (and I want to keep them that way). Therefore I will need to synchronize the controller queue because I don't think that even if I'll declare the queue `static` it will prevent synch issues. In addition if I use `synchronized` inside the controller then I'm not taking an advantage of the multi-threading model that Tomcat uses.

What is the best practice to save controller state/perform synchronization is such case?

This is my controller:

```
@RestController
public class TrackingEventController {

    @Autowired
    private DBHandler db;

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    private Queue<TrackingEvent> queue;

    public TrackingEventController() {
        this.queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(30);
    }

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @RequestMapping(method=GET, path=trackingEventPath)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleTrackingEvent(
            @RequestParam(name = Routes.event) String event,
            @RequestParam(name = Routes.pubId) String pubId,
            @RequestParam(name = Routes.advId) String advId) {

        TrackingEvent tr = new TrackingEvent(event, pubId, advId);

        this.trySendEventsMessage(tr);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    private synchronized void trySendEventsMessage() {
        this.queue.add(tr);
        if (this.queue.size() >= eventsMapMaxMessageSize) {
            jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(jmsTopicName, this.queue);
            queue.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a huge premature optimization to me. Databases are fast. Just insert directly from the controller. Added bonus: you won't lose data if your server crashes. Optimize only if you actually have a performance problem coming from these insertions. Especially given that you don't seem comfortable with concurrency yet.

Comment: I want to make a scalable solution going forward. More importantly I think it's a design pattern problem, and I'm not sure what's the best practice here.

Comment: There's a lot of solutions you can do here. The best practice would be to utilise spring data, configuring the service to write your events to the Database as they are received. You can, if you like, have these batch inserted but it would not be recommended as, in case of a sudden crash, your events would be irrecoverable. You'd first create a service layer and autowire your repository to it. Then you would call save on your Jpa/Crud repository implementation. Please see more on Spring Data here: https://spring.io/projects/spring-data